# How to implement a function change_value_at_index that takes in three parameters: a tuple, an index, and a new value?

Tags: python-3.x

Implement a function

```
change_value_at_index
```

that takes in three parameters: a tuple, an index, and a new value, and changes the value at the index to the new value. The function should return the modified tuple. If index is out of range, return the original tuple.

```
for example, change_value_at_index((1, 2, 3), 1, -1) =  (1, -1, 3)

for example, change_value_at_index((1, 2, 3, 4, 5), -2, 'huh') = (1, 2, 3, 'huh', 5)

def change_value_at_index(tpl, index, value):
    # Your code here
```

How do I do this? I am really clueless. Thanks for your help! Also, I must use Python 3.x.

Comment: This is not a web site where people automatically do your homework for you. Please show what you have tried, or try to explain what you are stuck with. For example: is it the fact that you must work with _tuples_ that is problematic? Would you know how to do this if the parameter and the result were _lists_ instead?

Comment: I know how the value and index works. when index = 1 and value = -1, it means replace 2 with -1 so that u get (1,-1,3). Yes, when I work with tuples, it is very problematic. Not sure how to write a function that does all the replacing of values at the appropriate position. Please enlighten me. Thanks! Lists, I also not very sure how to use it.

Comment: Ok; tuples and lists are almost the same thing and can be used in the same ways, with one exception: once a tuple is created, its contents cannot change. Therefore, the task is poorly worded: it's impossible to _modify_ a tuple; what you can do, however, is to _create a new tuple_. Since you want the new tuple to be different, you need to first create a list that contains the elements you want to have in your tuple, and then create a list based on that tuple.

Comment: So the first thing you should figure out is: if you have a _list_ of elements, say, `elements` (containing, for example, `[1, 2, 3]`), and a variable `index` that contains an index (for example, `1`), and a variable `value` that contains the new value, what would be the code for making the list contain `[1, -1, 3]`?

Comment: def change_value_at_index(tpl, index, value):
    # Your code here
    a = (tpl [0] ,-1,tpl [2] )
    return a

Comment: The problem with that solution is that it assumes that the tuple contains exactly three values, which might not be the case - also, it assumes that the value to be inserted is exactly `-1`, and that it is to be inserted at index `1`. How can you use the variables instead, to insert whichever value `value` contains? How can you use a variable to decide where to insert something in a list? (Again, we're going to have to solve this via lists, so pretend for now that you have a list rather than a tuple.)

Comment: My teacher only teach me tuple and wants me to use tuple. Still unclear how to start the question. Can you give me a example on how to start it. def change_value_at_index(tpl, index, value): ???

Comment: That is a rather weird approach. Has he/she tough you about tuple slicing (e.g. `tpl[0:2]`) and tuple concatenation (e.g. `(1, 2) + (3, 4)`)? That's the only way I know to solve this without going via lists.

Comment: He got teach tuple slicing and tuple concatenation. My answer is:def change_value_at_index(tpl, index, value):
    # Your code here
    if index >= len(tpl) or index < -len(tpl):
        return tpl
    else:
        a = tpl[0]
        for i in range(1, len(tpl)):
            a = tpl[:index] + (value,) + tpl[index+1:]
        return a Why wrong?

Comment: If you only look at `tpl[:index] + (value,) + tpl[index+1:]`, what does that expression produce in the two examples (one where `tpl` is `(1, 2, 3)`, `index` is `1`, and `value` is `-1`, and the other where `tpl` is `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`, `index` is `-2`, and `value` is `'huh'`)?

Comment: Thanks!!! I finally understand and know how to do it!

Comment: Great! (As you might be aware, you can mark your own answer as accepted.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def change_value_at_index(tpl, index, value):
    # Your code here
    if index >= len(tpl) or index < -len(tpl):
        return tpl
    else:
        a = tpl[:index] + (value,) + tpl[index+1:]
        return a
```